# passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

```
char s[2];
do{
    scanf("%s", s);
}while(strcmp(toupper(s[0]), "Y") == 0);
```

This gives me the following error:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  }while(strcmp(toupper(s[0]), "Y") == 0);
```

Why?

Comment: Whatever you do, **do not add a cast** to silence the (IMHO badly worded) warning.

Comment: @pmg how is it badly worded? the argument is an `int` even...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: maybe it's a translation thing. When I read the warning my first instinct is to add a cast which, in the case of the usual appearing of this warning, is the wrong thing to do. Maybe *"warning: dubious conversion from integer to pointer"* avoiding any (possibly mis-interpreted) suggestion would be better.

Answer (score 3):

The `toupper()` function case-converts a single character (ensures it is upper-case or not alphabetic) and returns the character.  The `strcmp()` function expects a pointer to a character, not a character.  That's why you get the error.  Use `while (toupper((unsigned char)s[0]) != 'Y')` as the condition in your `do … while` loop:

```
char s[2];
do {
    if (scanf("%1s", s) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected error scanning for a single character\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
 } while(toupper((unsigned char)s[0]) != 'Y');
```

Note the error handling, avoidance of buffer overflow, and avoidance of trouble with plain `char` values that are negative.  You could also sensibly use:

```
char c;
do {
    if (scanf(" %c", &c) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected error scanning for a single character\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
 } while(toupper((unsigned char)c) != 'Y');
```

This uses a single character input.  The leading blank in the format string is not an accident; it skips leading white space.  Three conversion specifiers don't skip leading white space — `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets) and `%n`.  All the others, including `%s` in particular, skip leading white space automatically, newlines and all.

Answer (score 1):

This may be not directly related to your question. But from a functional perspective, another possible solution I think would be to not use "toupper" at all.

```
char s[2];
do{
    if (scanf("%1s", s)) != 1) break;
}while( s[0] != 'Y'  && s[0] != 'y'  );
```

Comment: Thanks. You are absolutely right.  "Y" is a pointer and 'Y' is a char. Thanks for this.

Comment: `"Y"` is not a pointer; it's an array of 2 char (in many uses it gets converted to a pointer).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. That is exactly what I meant. Glad to see you make it clearer.